# How to modify browser properties / attributes with javascript after the window has been opened

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

How do i modify browser properties / attributes with javascript after the window has been opened (i.e. without using window.open('', '' ,'') and modifying attributes with the third parameter).  I need to do this because the window is already opened by java before hand and I want to modify it with javascript after it has already been opened.

Thank you.

Comment: Which browser attributes are you looking to modify exactly ??

Comment: toolbar, scrollbars, menubar, ect.. things that modofy the look and feel of the browser

Comment: you can do the samething using CSS !!

Comment: how so? please provide an answer so i can select it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you want to modify the look and feel of the users browser using JS & CSS.

Firstly, you  need to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect whether the users browser supports certain features or not.

And well for scrollbar, here's a quick [demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/) for using Webkit scrollbars on your website.

And for menubar, navbar, etc. you can use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), as it provides some popular user interface components.